# How to separate the command (FOR ... DO) if run in one line

Tags: windows, for-loop, cmd

For example:
`FOR /F "delims==" %G IN ('SET') DO @echo %G & pause`

After this command, a pause is set every time after a line is output.

But I need to pause after the output of **all** the lines (without batch file, only one command line).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands after `for ... in (...) do` are all considered as being placed in the loop body.
To change that behaviour you have to use parentheses, like this:

```cmd
(for /F "delims==" %G in ('SET') do @echo %G) & pause
```